# Bash Perl multiline match into variable

Tags: perl, variable, command-substitution

I am trying to extract 2 strings from a multiline text.

```
postmsg="\033[0;37m
Email 
Settings"
```

This line finds some match at the beginning of the string and puts it in a variable inCol.

```
inCol=$(perl -e 'print $1 if $ARGV[0]=~/^(\\033\[.*?m).*$/mi; ' -- "${postmsg}")
```

I also want to grab what is the rest of the string (basically the .*$)
I tried with this:

```
inVal=$(perl -e 'print $1 if $ARGV[0]=~/^\\033\[.*?m(.*)$/mi; ' -- "${postmsg}")
```

This actually works if my input is a one line string. If not, then nothing comes out.

`.*$` matches to end of line... tried with `\Z` but nothing. tried with `.*` alone, and nothing.

Tried with various modifiers etc... 
This must be very simple but I cannot find the answer.

**Even better, if this could be done in a single line.** instead of running the match twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and of course it was simple.

```
inVal=$(perl -e 'print $2 if $ARGV[0]=~/^(\\033\[.*?m)(.*)$/mis;' -- "${1}")
```

missing the 's' at the end

Comment: Why downvote?  Still interested if this can be done in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
inCol=${postmsg%%$'\n'*}
inVal=${postmsg#*$'\n'}
```

The first removes the longest suffix pattern `\n*`, the second removes the shortest prefix pattern `*\n`.